# How to filter a list by date condition?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to filter my list by looking for all items that have an end date less than or equal to today's date.

I know that in Liquid I can filter using `where:` to find items that match a condition. For example, if I wanted to get a list of today's conferences I could do:

```
{% assign todays_conferences = (site.conferences | where: 'date_end', today) %}
```

However, I can't do the same when I try to get upcoming conferences:

```
{% assign upcoming_conferences = (site.conferences | where: 'date_end', ??? | sort: 'date_start') %}
```

This is because I'm not looking to match a value one-to-one, but I'm trying to find items based on a date comparison. I have searched all over and unable to find a way.

How can I filter a list this way? I am hoping I wouldn't have to resort to looping through sequentially and doing an if statement on each row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Jekyll 3.2, Instead of using `where` you can use `where_exp` and filter the array with the objects where that expression is true:

```
  {% assign upcoming_conferences = (site.conferences | where_exp: 'date_end', 'date_end < site.time' | sort: 'date_start') %}
```

You may replace `site.time` with any other valid date.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected. This is due to the fact that you are comparing a Date Object with a Time object. I actually thought this would be the same thing as well. This is an ongoing issue on Jekyll at the moment. The solution that works is actually extending Jekyll's SiteDrop class and defining a @date. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5302

Comment: @Maxcell I've tested locally before posting and worked, can you give an example where it does not?

Comment: I am not quite sure why this particular project works the way that it does, however, their date does not properly process to being something like a clean Jekyll site may. In this [photo](http://imgur.com/a/hI6AP) you can see for some reason the item in their collection is a Date Object and the site is a Time object. I opened a new Jekyll project and confirmed your response and I will say you are correct, however, in this super unique cause it doesn't work. Will keep you posted!

Comment: Marking as accepted then, since the bug exists elsewhere.